# How to see the hardware benchmark results?

Tags: benchmarking, log, cli, hardware

Substrate has introduced a flag called `--no-hardware-benchmarks` to disable automatic hardware benchmarks. This implies if the flag is not set, the benchmark should run automatically at startup and measure the CPU speed. Without this benchmark and using the version of substrate which has this new CLI option, I was expecting to see a report that would give comparable figures to the configuration of substrate reference hardware:

```
SUBSTRATE_REFERENCE_HARDWARE =
        [
        {
            "metric": "Blake2256",
            "minimum": {
                "MiBs": 1029.0
            }
        },
        {
            "metric": "Sr25519Verify",
            "minimum": {
                "KiBs": 666.0
            }
        },
        {
            "metric": "MemCopy",
            "minimum": {
                "GiBs": 14.323
            }
        },
        {
            "metric": "DiskSeqWrite",
            "minimum": {
                "MiBs": 450.0
            }
        },
        {
            "metric": "DiskRndWrite",
            "minimum": {
                "MiBs": 200.0
            }
        }
      ]
```

However I couldn't find such logs when I started my node. Is my usage and expectation correct?

Comment: Sounds like you're using an older version of substrate? It's in master and I would think it's in the june / july 2022 monthly tags.

Answer (score 4):

A `v0.9.27` Polkadot node will print hardware and performance info on startup. It looks like this:

```sh
Parity Polkadot    
✌️  version 0.9.27-b017bad50d3    
❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2017-2022    
 Chain specification: Polkadot    
  Node name: ethereal-throne-1125    
⛓  Native runtime: polkadot-9270 (parity-polkadot-0.tx13.au0) 
   
# General hardware info
 Operating system: linux    
 CPU architecture: x86_64    
 Target environment: gnu
 CPU: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz    
 CPU cores: 4    
 Memory: 31831MB    
 Kernel: 5.15.0-43-generic    
 Linux distribution: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS    
 Virtual machine: no

# Hardware benchmarks
 CPU score: 1063MB/s    
 Memory score: 17465MB/s    
 Disk score (seq. writes): 2793MB/s    
 Disk score (rand. writes): 348MB/s 

 Highest known block at #0    
〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615
```

It is also the case for slightly earlier Polkadot versions.
You can see that there are two paragraphs of output that mention either hardware or its performance.
Now the `--no-hardware-benchmarks` flag will suppress this output by not running the benchmarks.

Additionally you can run them explicitly by calling `polkadot benchmark machine`.
This performs a longer and more precise benchmark. The output depends on your hardware:

```
Running machine benchmarks...    
+----------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Category | Function       | Score        | Minimum      | Result            |
+=============================================================================+
| CPU      | BLAKE2-256     | 994.00 MiB/s | 1.00 GiB/s   | ✅ Pass ( 96.6 %) |
|----------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------|
| CPU      | SR25519-Verify | 652.91 KiB/s | 666.00 KiB/s | ✅ Pass ( 98.0 %) |
|----------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------|
| Memory   | Copy           | 15.46 GiB/s  | 14.32 GiB/s  | ✅ Pass (107.9 %) |
|----------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------|
| Disk     | Seq Write      | 2.48 GiB/s   | 450.00 MiB/s | ✅ Pass (564.8 %) |
|----------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------|
| Disk     | Rnd Write      | 300.62 MiB/s | 200.00 MiB/s | ✅ Pass (150.3 %) |
+----------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
From 5 benchmarks in total, 5 passed and 0 failed (10% fault tolerance).    
The hardware meets the requirements
```

Comment: Is there a debug/log level that should be enabled for the above log to show up?

Comment: No. You can go to the [Release page](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases) and download a binary to try it out. Does it not work? Then please open an issue in [Substrate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate). Please note that Substrate only *officially* supports Linux, so I never tested in on Windows. The docker image prints it as well.

Comment: I’m testing it on Nodle parachain binary which is based on substrate branch: polkadot 0.9.26 and same cumulus branch version. I also ran “benchmark machine”. It took a while to execute meaning it was doing something but returned no logs.

Comment: Then that is an issue of the Nodle node, not Substrate in general. Could be that the command is not properly exposed or that something with the log level is wrong. You can probably open an issue in the Nodle repo and mention me (@ggwpez). Should look like [this](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/670d33c516044d4c25edeb00971b4501409256b6/cli/src/command.rs#L601).